# Android sound plays noisy and is crackling

Tags: java, android, audio

I am having problems with playing sound on android with the **SoundPool**, this works nicely with the MediaPlayer class. Why I can't use the MediaPlayer class is because it's not supporting the change of the sound pitch or speed.

The use case: Sound is played on background and it will be changed based on the user input.

The current problem: Does not play the sound correctly and freezes the application.

Question: What would be correct way to handle this situation, should the background sound played in separate thread and the communication of changing the sound volume should be done using **Handler** and messages ?

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    soundPool = new SoundPool(3, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    RAIN_SOUND_ID =  soundPool.load(getContext(), R.raw.rain, 1);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {


            soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {

                @Override
                public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
                    if (sampleId == RAIN_SOUND_ID) {
                        soundPool.play(RAIN_SOUND_ID, 1f, 1f, 10, -1, 1);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SoundPool class actually creates and manages it's own thread pool behind the scenes, for playing it's sounds. So you can simplify your code to remove your additional threading as a potential issue.

Comment: True, I'll try this later, if the soundpool has its own threading then it's safe to change the volume in the UI thread.

Comment: You were correct the soundpool has the separate thread and it's safe to modify the volume in UI thread.